# How to pass prop to component's children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const ListView = () => {
  return(
    <ul>
      <ListItem modal={<Modal />} />
    </ul>
  )
};

const ListItem = (props) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setVisible(!visible)

  return (
    <>
      <li>
        ListItem 
      </li>
      <ModalWrapper toggle={toggle}>{props.modal}</ModalWrapper>
    </>
  )
}

const ModalWrapper = (props) => {
  if(!props.visible) return null;
  return (
    <>
      {props.children}
    </>
  )
}

const Modal = ({ toggle }) => {
  /* I would like to use toggle() here. */
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={toggle} className="dimmer"></div> 
      <div className="modal">modal</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I have a function `toggle()` in `<ListItem />` as shown above.

I am struggling to use `toggle()` in `<Modal />`.

**Is it possible or are there any suggestions?**

Comment: This is a not a HOC, this is children as props. https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Please explain better what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `toggle` to `ModalWrapper` children, be careful not to override `toggle` prop on `Modal` after it.

```js
const ModalWrapper = ({ children, visible, toggle }) => {
  const injected = React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { toggle })
  );
  return <>{visible && injected}</>;
};
```

Refer to [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) and [React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap).

Demo:

[image: Edit SO-Q-56529259]